# How to fix "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed"?

Tags: python-3.x, iis, amazon-web-services

I know this question was asked here but no answers seem to solve my problem.

I have a server running in amazon-web-services. It is Windows 8 + IIS8. My website has a form with POST method. The website was developed with python 3.

On localhost everything works perfectly.

However, when I upload it and try to submit the form , I get this error:

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. The page you
>   are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP
>   verb) was used to attempt access.

As other answers suggest, there might be a problem with the "post" method, so I tried to change it to "get", and then I got this error:

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

I tried to running the website from the server via "localhost", so that I get a better information and here is what I got:

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
>
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>   method (HTTP verb) is being used.
>
> Most likely causes: •The request sent to the Web server used an HTTP
>   verb that is not allowed by the module configured to handle the
>   request. •A request was sent to the server that contained an invalid
>   HTTP verb. •The request is for static content and contains an HTTP
>   verb other than GET or HEAD. •A request was sent to a virtual
>   directory using the HTTP verb POST and the default document is a
>   static file that does not support HTTP verbs other than GET or HEAD.
>
> Things you can try: •Verify the list of verbs enabled for the module
>   handler this request was sent to, and ensure that this verb should be
>   allowed for the Web site. •Check the IIS log file to see which verb is
>   not allowed for the request. •Create a tracing rule to track failed
>   requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about
>   creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

I am not too good with configurations and got really confused. Could you please help to fix it?
here is my website (just fill the form and you will see the error): [nztracker.nz](http://nztracker.nz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in the directory that the website is was a file called "web.config"

When I copied the files of the website, I have accidentally deleted it. This file defined which handler to use for my *.py files. (or any other  language files you might use).

Using this: [https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/484](http://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/484) I have added a handler to my IIS and it has solved the problem